# Orden de elementos <strong> y <a> (buenas prácticas)

Tags: html, buenas-prácticas

Tanto si pongo

```
<strong><a href="enlace.html">ENLACE</a></strong>
```

como

```
<a href="enlace.html"><strong>ENLACE</strong></a>
```

voy a obtener el mismo resultado a nivel visual, ¿pero a nivel de buenas prácticas, hay un orden predefinido en el que se deben de escribir los elementos en HTML?

Lo pregunto porque en lenguajes como Java, los modificadores se pueden poner en cualquier orden pero se aconseja ponerlos en un orden determinado:

```
public / private / protected -> abstract -> static -> final -> transient -> volatile -> **default** -> synchronized -> native -> strictfp
```

¿Hay alguna especificación en HTML que recomiende un orden determinado de los elementos?

Comment: Este enlace podrá orientarte un poco: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document y también https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html que aunque es para HTML4 la mayoría de las cosas que dice se siguen aplicando.

Comment: Buena pregunta, pero yo te diría que ambas son válidas. No representan error ni de sintaxis ni de diseño, [la etiqueta `strong` es de énfasis](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-STRONG), puedes resaltar [tanto el enlace como el texto del enlace](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A). Solo conozco un punto a considerar, y es que en XHTML [se recomienda dejar el `strong` encerrando a la etiqueta `a`](http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/Creole1.0#section-Creole1.0-BoldAndOrItalicLinks). Aunque en lo personal, prefiero hacer lo contrario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la especificación de semántica de la **W3C** un elemento **`strong`**<sup>1</sup> esta destinado para:

- Denotar contenido que el usuario debe ver antes que el resto
- Denotar un aviso de *advertencia* o *precaución*
- Urgencia, seriedad e importancia del contenido a mostrar

Ahora si revisamos la doc.<sup>2</sup> de **Mozilla Developer** sobre la etiqueta **`anchor <a>`**, tiene su razón de existir para:

- Enlazar a páginas web externas
- Elementos internos del mismo sitio
- Emails
- etc.

Entonces la opción que considero con base en lo anterior, la mas adecuada sería:

```
<a href="enlace.html"><strong>ENLACE</strong></a>
```

Teniendo:

- Etiqueta HTML -> etiqueta **`strong`** ->contenido a resaltar o dar mayor importancia

Para que de esta forma, resaltemos la importancia de uno de los enlaces que tienes el cual tiene como texto **NOMBRE**.

Lo anterior pues así estás:

- Indicando relevancia mayor de este enlace por sobre los anteriores
- Te interesa que tenga mas sentido de urgencia el texto de esta ancla por sobre las demás

**Ejemplo basándome en la especificación de la W3C**

Deseo mostrar al usuario un párrafo donde va a tener mayor énfasis o importancia solicitarle que revise la documentación oficial quedando asi:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
      <p>
        el siguiente texto es mas relevante
        <strong>Continua investigando en la especificación de la W3C</strong>
      </p>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencias**

- [strong element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-strong)
- [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a)